# How to render an array to twig

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I've a block with values in the following array structure.

```
        $block['tag'][] = $term;
        $block['image'][] = $url;
        $block['title'][] = $title;
        $block['description'][] = $description;
```

From the function build in block, I'm passing it to theme as

```
$build = [
      '#theme' => 'allofus_four_grids_block',
      '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
      '#doubles' => array('key' => $block),
    ];
```

Then inside the module, I'm passing it to twig as

```
'allofus_four_grids_block' => [
      'variables' => [
        'block' => array('key' => array()),
      ],
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'basis') . '/templates/custom-blocks',
    ],
```

And in the twig I'm iterating it as

```
{% for key,value in block %}
    Key : {{ key }}
    Value : {{ value }}
    {% for key,text in value %}
        Key : {{ key }}
        Value : {{ text }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

But this is not giving me the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you declare

```
'allofus_four_grids_block' => [
      'variables' => [
        'block' => array('key' => array()),
      ],
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'basis') . '/templates/custom-blocks',
    ],
```

So you need to use the variable block :

```
$build = [
      '#theme' => 'allofus_four_grids_block',
      '#test_var' => $this->t('Test Value'),
      '#block' => array('key' => $block),
    ];
```

Not #doubles

Comment: How do I get it in twig?

Comment: you boucle like you do on block for the first level then another boucle for key